# Connecting NFTs to physical products by an NFC tag on the Solana blockchain with Dart / Flutter

Tags: reactjs, flutter, nfc, solana, nft

I'm interested in spinning up a collection of NFTs on Solana where the NFTs are connected to physical products via an NFC tag. What this means is each NFT has a unique url or asset contract, when you scan the NFC tag it directs the scanner to the NFT.

Ideally I'd like to do this how [Adidas does it where they "burn" the NFT when you redeem for the physical product](https://www.adidas.com/into_the_metaverse/faq) but I don't want to get too in over my head if that's too complicated. I don't want to create another NFT after the NFT is burned either.

I've seen several on Ethereum but am more interested in the Solana use case. Does anyone have any experience building these or have seen similar collections on Solana?

I've seen that [Metaplex](https://www.metaplex.com/) is an accelerator for React for spinning up NFTs but I'm unsure if it could be utilized. Ideally would like to use Dart / Flutter but if React is the only option then I could make it work